# How to convert string json to JSON object

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to get json object from another js file. I found out the end result is json in string form look like this

```
"[{ "part": "Part1", "dwg": "ASAD" }, { "part": "Part2", "dwg": "B" }];"
```

How can I convert into JSON object? Here is my code

```
var jsonData = $.get("/Scripts/dummy.js", function (data) {

            console.log(data);
            return data;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

use JSON.stringify().

var json = JSON.stringify(data);

Answer (score 0):

To convert a string to JSON object, use JSON.parse:

var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonText);

```
var jsonData = $.get("/Scripts/dummy.js", function (data) {

        console.log(data);
        return  JSON.parse(data);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need is JSON.parse():

```
var json = '[{ "part": "Part1", "dwg": "ASAD" }, { "part": "Part2", "dwg": "B" }]';
JSON.parse(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to remove the trailing the `;` from your object string and use proper single/double quote wrapping:

```
// Your string used all double quotes, replace the outermost quotes with single 
// quotes as shown below. Also notice that the ; has been moved outside the 
// string, semicolons are not permitted as part of JSON object strings
var x = '[{ "part": "Part1", "dwg": "ASAD" }, { "part": "Part2", "dwg": "B" }]';
```

and then use `JSON.parse()` to return a valid JSON object:

```
JSON.parse(x);
=> [ { part: 'Part1', dwg: 'ASAD' },
     { part: 'Part2', dwg: 'B' } ]
```